# Unable to resize launcher icon in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in Virtual Box.

I am facing the launcher icon resize issue since yesterday. Hence I deleted the VM and installed a new instance. Facing the issue still.

If I run unity it's working for that moment, but doesn't give a permanent solution. Please Help... Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: *"launcher icon resize issue"* which is.........

Comment: i have changed the launcher icon size to 20. but the icons are still of the default size. Please refer the screenshot.

Comment: Try this command in terminal  `gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/  icon-size 20`

Comment: @Serg It is not working for me.

Comment: ok, that's means something is really wrong with your Unity shell.  GUI option and command line option do the same thing. So here we can rule out problem with the System Settings menu. Can't suggest much more - never seen this happen before. Consider trying to purge and reinstall Unity shell. You can always temporarily switch to another shell, gnome for instance

Comment: if i run unity in tty it's working fine... but i have to do that every time i boot the system.

Comment: Could you help with switching to another shell? @Serg

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell` . After it is installed you can select `Gnome` on login screen.

Answer (score 4):

In VirtualBox <strike>5.1.4 r110228 with the same version of VirtualBox extensions installed in Ubuntu 16.04,</strike> enabling 3D Acceleration (Settings... > Display > Screen > Enable 3D Acceleration) fixed the launcher icon resize issue.

[image]
Virtual machine settings

<strike>Unfortunately, I also had to disable Hardware Acceleration in Google Chrome running in the VM otherwise Chrome just appeared as a black window.</strike>

**Update 1**
In addition to enabling 3D Acceleration, install VirtualBox Guest Additions from the Ubuntu repo instead of inserting the VirtualBox CD image:

```
apt install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

VirtualBox Guest Additions from the Ubuntu repo fixed rendering issues with Chrome and VS Code.

Comment: This didn't worked for me.

Comment: I need to keep 3d disabled otherwise the mouse disappears (and this is nothing to do with mouse integration - it just vanishes sometimes regardless of that setting).

Comment: With the same issue, this fix works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on suddenly power off & I try almost everything & they didn't work, exept this:

Install "CompizConfig Settings Manager" from Ubuntu software manager & run it

Then click on "Advance search" that locate above close button & search for "launcher" word then click in the Plugin state on "Ubuntu Unity Plugin " then click in the Group state on "Launcher" then scroll down & set 48 to your favorite size, mine is 20 [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7FtE.jpg)